# Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException in MonoGame when calling string from a stored xnb file path

Tags: xna, texture2d, monogame

(I am using VS2012 Ultimate to make Windows Phone 8 Game with MonoGame)

So I have a class called ImagePathStorer.
The purpose of the class is to store the string path from my xnb background file so, instead of writing below code in my LoadContent method (in DrawableGameComponent):

```
_bg = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Resources/Images/Backgrounds/Loading");
```

I can write this instead to make it cleaner, and easier to maintain:

```
_bg = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(images.getBackgroundsPath(BackgroundName.Loading));
```

Note :

_bg is a Texture2D object.

BackgroundName is an enum to store the name of Backgrounds in my project.

And this is the ImagePathStorer class :

```
public class ImagePathStorer
{
    private List<string> backgroundsPath;
    public ImagePathStorer()
    {
        InitBackgroundsPath();
    }
    private void InitBackgroundsPath()
    {
        backgroundsPath = new List<string>();

        backgroundsPath.Insert((int)BackgroundName.Battle, @"Resources/Images/Backgrounds/Battle");
        backgroundsPath.Insert((int)BackgroundName.Loading, @"Resources/Images/Backgrounds/Loading");
        backgroundsPath.Insert((int)BackgroundName.Option, @"Resources/Images/Backgrounds/Option");
        backgroundsPath.Insert((int)BackgroundName.Start, @"Resources/Images/Backgrounds/Start");
        backgroundsPath.Insert((int)BackgroundName.Tutorial, @"Resources/Images/Backgrounds/Tutorial");
    }
}
```

But when I compiled it, there is an error message from :

```
_bg = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(images.getBackgroundsPath(BackgroundName.Loading));
```

....which says : "ContentLoadException was unhandled by user code" "An exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occured in MonoGame.Framework.DLL but was not handled in user code"

I've tried this one instead :

```
_bg = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("@"+images.getBackgroundsPath(BackgroundName.Loading));
```

but the results are no different. Any idea? Big thanks.

Comment: Answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228362/how-to-set-xnb-files-on-monogame-windows-phone-8-game-project

Comment: You could also follow this blog post [ http://wblo.gs/dVU ] to integrate XNA's Content Pipeline project with your MonoGame project to ensure your content files are always in the right place.