# How to set xnb files on Monogame Windows Phone 8 Game project?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, monogame

I never found any tutorial to make xnb files works. They are all using non Windows Phone 8 (Win 8 metro, etc) way.

Can someone guide me to make my xnb files workable at MonoGame Windows Phone 8 Game project? Because nothing I googled is doing any good.

Also, can I create an XNB using XNA Windows Game Project (with VS 2010) or does it need the project to be Windows Phone Game (I haven't Installed WPhoneSDK 7.1, but have installed the 8th in VS2012)

I so far use several ways and keep resulting in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ContentLoadException

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Compile the assets into xnb's using the [XnaContentCompiler](https://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/).
2. Put the files in the content folder that is created with your MonoGame template.
3. Change the properties to `Build Action = Content` and Copy to `Output Directory = Copy if Newer`.
4. Do your normal thing `var t = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"TextureName");`.

Comment: Thanks for the tool. Until now I was using a separate XNA content project which I was building separately in order to obtain the XNB's.