# How to use Xna Content Compiler on visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio-2013, monogame

I saw this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228362/how-to-set-xnb-files-on-monogame-windows-phone-8-game-project) so I downloaded and tried to run but I've never used XNA and the website from the link doesn't have any instruction/documentation...

Anyone who uses it have any suggestions?

(I don't have xna... I'm trying to use monogame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another rather classic solution is to install XNA framework included in Windows Phone SDK 7, create a separate XNA solution just for the purpose of building XNB files.

To get XNA working on your computer (for VS2010 - VS2013) first download Windows Phone SDK 7 and 8 (both of them) from here:
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

And then you can install XNA implementation for VS2010 - VS2013 from here:
https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases

Once all is installed, just create a new XNA Game solution. XNA will automatically create two projects for you, one of which is "Content" project, where you can place all your assets (pictures, sounds, fonts). After compilation you will get your XNB files created.

Comment: I just deleted XNA installer an VS 2010... tried to install xna after vs but it showed some error message and didnt install... (is it compatible with windows 8.1?)

I tried to use the Xna Content Compiler on VS 2013 but it says that can't load Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, Version 3.1.0.0

Comment: I am currently using XNA on Win8.1, with WP8.1 device and VS2013 Ultimate. So yes, it works. I just did a fresh install couple days ago. Just install Windows Phone SDK 7 and 8, then again install XNA from the codeplex.com link above.

Comment: but is it mandatory to get stuff for windows phone? I'm planning on develop for desktop only... If it is really mandatory then I guess Ill try

Comment: I'm not sure about desktop development. You did not specify you wanted to develop for desktop and I somehow assumed Windows Phone. However, I can confirm that having all the WP SDK and XNAs installed, XNA desktop app development works as well.

Comment: hum... but did you install visual studio 2013 after xna? I just tried to install sdk 7.1 and had some compatibility issues

Comment: No, I had the VS2013 installed before. I was trying to compile XNA project and it didn't work. Then I installed the XNA from the codeplex link above and it still didn't work (for my WP project type). After that I installed WP SDK and it started working well. So I kind of went backwards and it still worked.

Comment: SDK 8.0 says it need 5 GB of storage, is that correct? o.o

Comment: Somehow it worked but I think I didn't need to install the SDK... I think last time I downloaded the wrong version of XNA, ty bro